# C++ TTmath: Power of?

Tags: c++, math, ttmath

How can I get the power of two ttmath::UInt's in C++?
Math.pow works only on ints and the "^" operator isnt the power operator.

Anybody know this?

Answer (score 1):

The class `ttmath::Uint` has a method `Pow` defined, so you can just say

```
a.Pow(b)
```